# sed - loop only replaces the last language in a occurences - it should replace all

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to loop over multiple languages ti be replace in a string.
And I'm unsure if this is even the right way or what my mistake is.

Here is my code

```
langkeys=${LANG_KEYS}

for key in ${langkeys}
do

  sed -n "s/test.${key}/www.test.${key}.newdomain/g ;p" test.txt > /new-2.txt

done
```

Rc File

```
LANG_KEYS="de
at
pl
"
```

My problem is, only the pl language is being replaced.

EDIT:

How could i export the domains ?

Here is my idea in the RC FILE:

```
DOMAIN="test"
DOMAIN_SUFFIXE="test.net"

    sed -f <(printf 's/${DOMAIN}\.%s/www.${DOMAIN}.&.${DOMAIN_SUFFIX}/g\n' ${LANG_KEYS})  test.txt > /new-2.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this single `sed` and avoid any loop:

```sh
sed -f <(printf 's/test\.%s/www.&.newdomain/g\n' $LANG_KEYS) test.txt > /new-2.txt
```

Or if you want to get only matched lines:

```sh
sed -nf <(printf 's/test\.%s/www.&.newdomain/gp\n' $LANG_KEYS) test.txt > /new-2.txt
```

---

Fix to your attempted edited script:

```sh
LANG_KEYS="de
at
pl
"
DOMAIN="test"
DOMAIN_SUFFIX="net"

sed -f <(printf "s/$DOMAIN\.%s/www.&.$DOMAIN_SUFFIX/g\n" $LANG_KEYS) test.txt > /new-2.txt
```

Comment: Why do i need to printf ? Also if i understand correctly '&' will be replaced with the language from the array ?

Comment: `printf` generated sed commands for each of the language in variable `$LANG_KEYS`. Just run `printf 's/test\.%s/www.&.newdomain/gp\n' $LANG_KEYS` to see that.

Comment: Hey. I have a follow up quesiton. Could you maybe look at the edited version ?

Comment: It is not fair to change nature of question like this after getting a working answer. In case you have additional issue better to post a new question. Anyway what do you mean by `How could i export the domains?`